# How to set the default-value for a maven array parameter?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, default-value

I have a parameter in my custom plugin that is an array. If the parameter isn't given anything, I want to set the default-value to be a blank array. Of course, here is the normal syntax for a regular variable:

```
/**
* @parameter default-value="Hello Maven World"
*/
private String message;
```

But my array is set like this:

```
/**
* @parameter
*/
private String[] message;
```

How would I set the default-value of an array variable as a parameter in a custom maven plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to set the default values directly in the code instead of using a tag. This value can still be overridden in the pom file.

```
/**
 * @parameter
 */
private String[] message = new String[0];
```

That will give you an empty array.